# Could not agree on the correct answer on the following question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics, buoyancy

The following question was asked in a national teacher selection examination, and there were opposition based on the fact that the announced key was wrong and it should be changed. The question is translated from Turkish.

```
A container filled with water is put in a stationary elevator. A solid ball is placed in the water and it floats on the surface of the water.
When the elevator starts moving upwards with acceleration *a*, which of the following statements is/are true? 

   I. The ball sinks more. 
  II. The buoyant force applied to the ball increases. 
 III. Buoyant force is equal to the weight of the ball.

A)  Only I      B) Only II    C) Yalnız III    D) I and II     E) I and III
```

The announced correct answer is D.

My understanding of how the force is transferred in the water is shaky. A colleague states that the in initial states of the accelerated motion, the water near the edges of the container will feel the force before the water in the middle and hence starts moving before. The ball due to its inertia and the not being informed yet of the force stays stationary (for a very small time) and then it also starts moving with acceleration *a*.

For me, it is not clear as to why the water in different parts of the container would react differently to the force applied by the bottom of the container (any textbook/article reference to clarify this would be much appreciated). Also, during the discussion, another colleague argued that the ball will return, given sufficient time, to the original equilibrium position during the accelerated motion, hence the first statement is wrong. If this is true, what would be the reason for ball to return to the initial equilibrium position?

Comment: You have missed an important part of the question.  Before the acceleration is the ball floating? If it is then the correct answer is not listed.